# Cylinder isotopy relative to its bases

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Is n-times twisted cylinder isotopic to 0-times twisted cylinder relative to its bases? (I hope I got the terms right)
That is, is it possible to twist (stretching, bending etc. is allowed) a cylinder in 3 dimensions without moving its bases at all?
For n=2k the answer is yes (stretch the middle, flip the lower part over the top base, straighten, repeat k times) and it seems like for n=1 it is no.

Any hints and directions are welcome.

**Edit**: Adding formal problem statement.
Let $X=S^1\times[0,1]$, $K=S^1\times\{0, 1\} \subset X$. $f_n: X\rightarrow \mathbb R^3; f_n(\varphi, t) = (\cos(\varphi+2\pi nt), \sin(\varphi+2\pi nt), t), \varphi \in [0,2\pi), t \in [0,1]$. Is $f_n$ isotopic to $f_0$ relative to $K$?

**Edit**: Adding a visualization for $f_0$ and $f_2$ isotopy.
[image: f_0 and f_2 isotopy illustration]

We can keep all the twisting near points a and b. Each gets a $2\pi$ twist.
And the direction of the twist is the same as they are both "left-threaded" in steps 2-4 and steps 4-5 don't make them "right-threaded", so they combine to a $4\pi$ twist as in $f_2$.

Comment: what is an $n$-times twisted cylinder?

Comment: The cylinder is a product of 2d sphere S2 and [0,1]. Now we can embed/map it into 3d space with $n$ twists this way $(\cos(\phi + n * t * 2\pi), \sin(\phi + n * t * 2\pi), t)$ where $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$ and $t \in [0,1]$. These are continuous mappings, and they are equal for $t$ equal 0 or 1, i.e. on the cylinder's bases.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand... when you say "product of 2d spheres S2 and [0,1]" what do you mean?. The map you define seems to me like a map $S^1\times [0,1]\to \mathbb R^3$

Comment: Thanks, I should have said "the cylindrical surface is $S^1 \times [0, 1]$" and it can be mapped "$n$-times twisted" to $\mathbb R^3$ via the given map. I believe that this problem has the same answer for twisted "cylindrical surface" and twisted "solid cylinder".

Comment: So, in this case I think these maps are never isotopic. Could you explain better what do you mean by "stretch the middle, flip the lower part over the top base, straighten, repeat k times"?

Comment: I've tried to draw it. The key is that point a passes between points b and c in transition from 3rd to 4th step. And the tricky part to figure out is that the result is $f_2$ and not $f_1$.  [image](http://i.imgur.com/VbwMgDQ.png)

Comment: I'm afraid your map is not an isotopy. But in your picture I don't quite understand who are $S^1\times\{0\}$ and $S^\times\{1\}$

Comment: They are the lower and the upper ends ($z=0$ and $z=1$) of the image of $X$. Why isn't it an isotopy? It seems clear to me that all steps are embeddings (well, the image is in $\mathbb R^2$ and images look like lines, but objects they represent are homeomorphic to cylindrical surface surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$) and they can be connected continuously.

Comment: I see intersections in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make a better presentation then.

Comment: This is surely true; your isotopy between $f_n$ and $f_{n+2}$ is known in some circles as the `Kirby belt trick' that shows that the generator of $\pi_1(SO(3))$ has order 2. There are nice pictures of this in Kauffman's book, On Knots, pages 93-94. That $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ are not isotopic is trickier; you have to show that an isotopy would imply that the aforementioned generator is trivial in the fundamental group (which it isn't).

Comment: @Danny Ruberman, I must say I never heard the belt trick referred to as the "Kirby belt trick".

Comment: Dear @Dmitry Ivankov, do you allow the isotopy to modify the derivatives on $K$ along the $[0,1]$ direction? Or do you demand that the isotopy is constant on a neighbourhood of $K$?

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade, isotopy should be constant only on $K$. But it seems to me (haven't checked the whole proof of it) that for any such isotopy there must exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $K$ can be extended to $[0-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon]$ without breaking the isotopy.

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade, oops this statement is false. But still, it looks like if there is an isotopy, then it can be used to construct an isotopy constant in the neighbourhood of $K$.